# Any clue how to read a .style (ArcGIS) file in Python, for converting into another platform-specific format?

Tags: python, arcgis, qgis

The problem I am face with is that I have all my data as shapefiles but my organization works with only 1 ArcGIS license. Migrating to QGIS to prominent amount of work, I need to convert my ArcGIS .style file to the .sld format of QGIS, to ensure uniformity of data capture and maps.

I am working with Python for this, Could anyone give me any suggestions?